# YouTube API Playlist Index Appears Not To Be Zero-Based

Tags: youtube-api

I have a YouTube player embedded in my website with the src set to the following URL format:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=[playlistId]&index=0&rel=0&autoplay=1
```

The index parameter does not appear to be working correctly. **The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements) says the index is 0-based.** However, values of 0 or 1 will both play the 1st video in my playlist, a value of 2 will play the 2nd video, 3 will play the 3rd video, and so on. **It would appear the index is 1-based despite what the documentation says.**

Supporting my assumption, go to YouTube and view a playlist ([like this one)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J---aiyznGQ&list=PLbpi6ZahtOH4IeIP_heQHaLwElwKeJn-F). Hover over one of the videos in the list and observe the URL. The URL for the first video will have an index = 1, the second video will have index = 2, etc.

Obviously I can update the code in my site to use a 1-based index and fix my issue. However, I would like some confirmation that the index is indeed supposed to be 1-based and that YouTube isn't going to come back later and "fix" the index to be 0-based as described in the documentation, thus breaking my site again.

Comment: `It would appear the index is 1-based despite what the documentation says.` The documentation talks about the API, not about the URL.

Comment: @tkausl are you able to direct me to some documentation on the URL? I've not been able to find any. 

I tested generating the embed through the API and the 0-based index does indeed work correctly that way. Why would the API use a 0-based index while the URL uses 1-based?

Comment: @jtrohde probably the documentation is no up-to-date. Maybe on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) they can point you to some documentation or they will leave it as *to-do*.